# How to solve GPG problem on Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-windows, gpg

I'm having problem with GPG on emacs. It keeps saying

```
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for [some_weird_code_here] created at [date_here] using RSA Command output:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `c:/Users/[user]/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg'
gpg: Signature made [date_here] using RSA key ID [some_code]
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

How can I solve this gpg problem in GNU Emacs on my Windows 10 PC (64-bit)?

I googled the issue but still don't know how to solve it. Read some websites, installed Gpg4win software, etc. Thanks beforehand. I don't know what the gpg is, but that's another issue. I just want to solve this problem and go on with my own issues.

Answer (score 1):

GPG is just an implementation of the PGP encryption standard, you can read more about it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG); `gpg` keys can be a real pain, particularly on Windows, maybe try downloading the key and then using `M-x package-import-keyring` from within emacs to load the key manually?